# Ломается позиционирование FlexBox с середины в начало

Tags: css, flexbox

Проблема следующая: при введении ширины и высоты ломается позиционирование flexbox с середины в начало.

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: center;
width: 1170px;
height: 564px;
```

Comment: Можете добавить html к вашему CSS чтобы наглядно увидеть Вашу проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Так как не видно всего вашего кода, могу предположить что ваш flex лежит внутри другого блока. В этом случае родителю тоже надо задать display: flex;
Пример рабочего кода:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="flex">
        <p>Текст внутри флекса</p>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
    .flex {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: center;
        width: 1170px;
        height: 564px;
        background-color: red;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;

    }
</style>
```